# SharePoint - Create some kind of filter

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have to do some filtering on the datagrid I have displayed (a LOT of data). At first I thought about using Enterprise Search but it only search. I need to filter by columns I have on my DataGrid.

My solution would be injecting some JS to create some input fields and handle filtering. Do you have any other better "out-of-box" ideas?

Comment: is your data coming from SharePoint list?

Comment: @love thakker - yes :) . For now my best chance is probably injecting JS....

Anybody have any other idea?

Comment: You can make view in that list fetch your required data & columns. Display that view in listviewwebpart. 

SharePoint provides filter and short functionality by itself. you can use it.